# Apache web server and microservices with Docker

Tags: apache, docker, microservices

I have a few spring boot microservices running on Docker, and Apache web server (also running on Docker) for all the static stuff. The microservices are consumed by the web browser. Problem is, I don't know how I should reference the microservices from html or javascript:

- the microservice runs on a different port
- also might run on a different host
- the browser complains about links

Googling the problem points me toward Netflix eureka or Apache Camel, but I'm not sure these are the right solutions.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to do [Cross-Origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: The problem starts with the decision to let your browser access the different microservices. The typical thing to do is to put everything behind 1 thing (a load-balancer or a reverse proxy)

Comment: You could put your services behind Netflix Zuul as API Gateway, the user calls a domain depending on the parth zuul redirects directly to the java application (you can do this also without a webserver if you put a webserver before zuul) Maybe this might help you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_zuul_proxy_server_and_routing.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first think about deployment. You mention that the Docker containers might run on different machines. I recommend using container orchestrators like [Docker Swarm](https://github.com/docker/swarm) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) to manage a cluster and communication between microservices (typically via DNS).

Generally, you want to hide all your microservices behind one API path. The outside world does not need to know that your server application consists of multiple microservices. You can use a simple reverse proxy for this. I personally like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) because you can configure the routing paths in the Docker ecosystem via labels.

You say you consume the microservice APIs with a browser, so is it a web client application? If so, I recommend serving it as Docker container as well and embed it into the routing by using relative paths. E.g. UI is served as `/` and microservices as `/api/{service}/{path}`. Then the UI application can use relative paths because they are served by the same reverse proxy and such under the same URL (=> no CORS issues). Additionally, you can deploy to any IP, the routing stays the same and does not have to be adjusted